# Default Loop don't work in Wordpress 3.5

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm having some trouble calling a loop on a Wordpress Page other than the default article page.

This is my code I'm using:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
</div>
```

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
</div>
```

That doesn't show up anything.

But if I only use the query:

```
    <?php query_posts('showposts=10'); 
                        $ids = array(); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                        $ids[] = get_the_ID(); the_title(); the_content(); endwhile;
                    ?>
```

It works, but I - of course can't style the entries.

Can anybody help?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=10'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="navigation">
        <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```